# Overwriting an array value in PHP, puts it in the wrong place

Tags: php

This is the json I'm working with:

```
{
    "rsid": "xyz",
    "globalFilters": [
        {
            "type": "segment",
            "segmentId": "123"
        },
        {
            "type": "dateRange",
            "dateRange": "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000/2019-02-01T00:00:00.000"
        }
    ],
    "metricContainer": {...
```

I'm trying to replace the value of the dateRange with this code:

```
$data = json_decode($data,true);
$data['globalFilters'][0]['dateRange'] = $daterange;
$data = json_encode($data);
echo ($data);
```

But it results in adding this value under the segment ID: "123" like this:

```
{
    "rsid": "xyz",
    "globalFilters": [
        {
            "type": "segment",
            "segmentId": "123"
            "dateRange": "NEWRANGE"
        },
        {
            "type": "dateRange",
            "dateRange": "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000/2019-02-01T00:00:00.000"
        }
    ],
    "metricContainer": {...
```

Can anyone please help me understand how to correct this?

Comment: Thats because that field is in occurance 1 not 0 `$data['globalFilters'][1]['dateRange'] = $daterange;` So its just a typo

Comment: Shouldn't it be the second item of array `"globalFilters"`: `$data['globalFilters'][1]['dateRange'] = $daterange;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you are accessing the wrong variable. You need to access

```
$data['globalFilters'][1]['dateRange'] = $daterange;
```

Comment: i am sorry if my message was a little miss spelled not native english